# Display products from Woocommerce in external application

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I have a question about integration e.g. Woocommerce with external app.
What is the best and safe method to accomplish this goal?
Woocommerce has REST API but it might be quite vulnerable and will not show anything (products etc.) to non logged user(which is understandable).
Only safe idea that's comes to my mind is creating scripts inside WordPress and access them via AJAX but I'm worrying about performance of this method.
Maybe there is a right way that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: WooCommerce Api's work with a key system so it should be quite save https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose, you should create an API from scratch of the wordpress database. wordpress databse has all of you need in a good way and only some php codes needed to create and execute the API. then in you app with AJAX you should access that.

this link may help you:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/08/simple-rest-api-php

Answer (score 0):

The right way is likely creating your own API if you don't want to use Woocommence's one. That means you make a plan of what you need to expose, all the routes and start building the API. I warmly recommend the book by `Phil Sturgeon - Build APIs you won't hate`. The author is also a co-founder of https://phptherightway.com/ so it's quite reputable.